# Touch swipe coordinates using quo.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, drag, swipe

I'm building a web app using quo.js to handle touch events.

When the user swipes (drags) with one finger, I can use the following quo.js code to recognise this and apply a css transformation:

```
$$('element').swipe(function() {
  $('element').vendor('transform','translate(-100px,-100px)');
});
```

Now what I want to do is apply the translate amount based on the amount of swipe. In other words, I need to get the X/Y coordinates of the swipe. Does anyone know if this is possible using quo.js or do I need to use a different js library?

I tried this to get coordinates but it returns 'undefined':

```
$$('element').swipe(function(e) {
  alert(e.pageX);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event object quo.js passes to the callback contains a `currentTouch` object holding the x and y coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/UupmU/1/

```
$$('selector').swipe(function(e){
  console.log('swipe');
  console.log(e.currentTouch); // Gives position when gesture is cancelled 
});
```

Note that the swipe event only fires when a swipe gesture is completed. As far as I understood your use case it would be more convenient to use the `swiping` event, which fires as soon as a swipe gesture is detected and during all movements until release:

```
var $swipeable = $$('.swipeable'),
    swipeableHeight = $swipeable.height(),
    swipeableWidth = $swipeable.width();

$swipeable.swiping(function(e){
   var x = e.currentTouch.x - swipeableWidth / 2;
   var y = e.currentTouch.y - swipeableHeight / 2;

   $swipeable
     .vendor('transform', 'translate(' + x +'px,'+ y +'px)');
});
```

Comment: If I had the ability, I would give you a billion plus points for this. I think I've got a brain hemorrhage spending the last few hours trying to work this out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Out of interest, how did you know about the currentTouch? I can't find any documentation on that anywhere!

Comment: `console.log`: As quo.js works on desktop browsers you can simple do `$el.on('event', console.log)` and see what is passed into the event hander in your browser's js console. I prefer the Chrome dev tools (Open via: View - Developer - Javascript console), but all modern browsers have decent debugging functionality.

Comment: To follow up on this: There are various options for debugging mobile web browsers (e.g. Safari and Chrome remote debugging). For some quick and dirty console output http://jsconsole.com/ is just enough.

Comment: Ah yeh I can see a whole bunch of useful information in there. But I can't see currentTouch in the list... I see stuff like type, timestamp, currentTarget etc. (I'm using Firebug console in Firefox). Where abouts is that exact bit of info?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's something else in the event handler that gives how much distance the swipe has gone. For example -50px from swipe start. Your code above isn't quite right for dragging an element with the swipe but that would do that trick.

Comment: Without testing it at all: The event object for `swiping` holds `originalEvent.iniTouch`. Should be the first coordinates after gesture detection / on touch start. By substring from currentTouch you should be able to calculate the delta.

Comment: Yeh buddy! That's what I'm talking about.